# How do I fetch sorted logs in Cassandra?

Tags: sorting, logging, cassandra, database-performance, database-partitioning

In my application we store logs in Cassandra. User can see the logs after giving a start and an end date for the logs. We fetch the data on the basis of these dates and have implemented pagination as well such that the end date of page one becomes the start date for page 2.

Table:

```
CREATE TABLE audit_trail (
    account_id bigint,
    user_id bigint,
    time timestamp,
    category int,
    ip_address text,
    action_description text,
    additional_data map<text,text>,
    source int,
    source_detail varchar,
    PRIMARY KEY ( (account_id), time )
     ) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (time DESC);
```

Problem:

The logs we get are not sorted but scattered. For example upon hitting the query for logs of day 1 to 10 we might be getting logs for day 10,8,9,2,1, or in any other order.

Aim:

1. to get the logs in sorted order such that logs from day 1 are shown at the top then day 2 and so on.
2. no data shuffling. As, upon collision the table is restructured in Cassandra which might give in data we already have seen in page 1 on page 2 again.

Data throughput is large, usually around 1000 logs per  hour.

Comment: what is the data model..

Comment: CREATE TABLE billing.domain_event (
     date text,
     user_id bigint,
     domain_id bigint,
     type text,
     subtype text,
     event text,
     event_counter counter,
     PRIMARY KEY ( ( user_id, date ), domain_id, type, subtype, event )
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (domain_id ASC, type ASC, subtype ASC, event ASC);

Comment: Ideal scenario with your table structure will be fire separate query for each date..

Comment: are you saying that I should partition my database on the basis of Days?

Comment: Will be glad if you can highlight changes I will need to make with the data model.

Comment: No.. with your existing table considering `date` column has only date part the you can use query like `SELECT * FROM table WHERE user_id=? AND date=?`.. so for 10 days fire 10 queries..

Comment: So, what we are doing is showing activity logs from startDate till endDate with pagination size of 1000. Now what if the first query gets data more than 1000 then we will be using rest of the queries with no purpose. Buckets is a viable option but there will be synchronization problem with the replicas with that. 

Any option to reduce this overhead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (time DESC);

Adding this at the end of the table solved the problem for me.